# Scala reflection with Serialization (over Spark) - Symbols not serializable

Tags: scala, serialization, reflection, apache-spark

To begin with I'm using scala 2.10.4 and the example above is run in Spark 1.6 (though I doubt Spark has anything to do with this, it's just a serialization issue).

So here's my problem: assume I have a trait `Base` that is implemented by say two classes `B1` and `B2`. Now I have a generic trait that is extended by a collection of classes, one of them being over subtypes of `Base` e.g. (here I keep Spark's notion of RDD, but it could be something else actually as soon as it is serialized; Something  is just a result no matter what actually):

```
trait Foo[T] { def function(rdd: RDD[T]): Something }
class Foo1[B <: Base] extends Foo[B] { def function(rdd: RDD[B]): Something  = ... }
class Foo2 extends Foo[A] { def function(rdd: RDD[A]): Something  = ... }
...
```

Now I need an object that will take an `RDD[T]` (assume no ambuiguity here, it's just a simplified version) an that returns `Something` corresponding to the result of function corresponding with type `T`. But it should also work for `Array[T]` with a merging strategy. So far it looks like:

```
object Obj {
   def compute[T: TypeTag](input: RDD[T]): Something = {
      typeOf[T] match {
         case t if t <:< typeOf[A] => 
            val foo = new Foo[T]
            foo.function(rdd)
         case t if t <:< typeOf[Array[A]] => 
            val foo = new Foo[A]
            foo.function(rdd.map(x => mergeArray(x.asInstance[Array[A]])))
         case t if t <:< typeOf[Base] => 
            val foo = new Foo[T]
            foo.function(rdd)
         // here it gets ugly...
         case t if t <:< typeOf[Array[_]] => // doesn't fall through with Array[Base]... why?
            val tt = getSubInfo[T](0)
            val tpe = tt.tpe
            val foo = new Foo[tpe.type]
            foo.function(rdd.map(x => (x._1, mergeArray(x._2.asInstanceOf[Array[tpe.type]]))
      }
   }

   // strategy to transform arrays of T into a T object when possible
   private def mergeArray[T: TypeTag](a: Array[T]): T = ... 

  // extract the subtype, e.g. if Array[Int] then at position 0 extracts a type tag for Int, I can provide the code but not fondamental for the comprehension of the problem though
   private def getSubInfo[T: TypeTag](i: Int): TypeTag[_] = ... 
}
```

Unfortunatly, it seems to work fine on a local machine, but when it gets sent to Spark (serialized), I get a `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` with:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$PackageClassSymbol
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$PackageClassSymbol, value: package types)
    - field (class: scala.reflect.internal.Types$ThisType, name: sym, type: class scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol)
```

I do have a workaround (quite obvious, enumerate possibilities), but for my curiosity, is there a way to fix this? And why aren't Symbol serializable whereas their equivalents in Manifests were?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeTags are generally now serializable in scala but, oddly, not types directly (this is odd because typetags contain symbols which are not :-/).

This might do what you want

```
// implicit constructor TypeTag parameter is serialized.
abstract class TypeAware[T:TypeTag] extends Serializable {
  def typ:Type = _typeCached

  @transient
  lazy val _typeCached:Type = typeOf[T]
}

trait Foo[T] extends Serializable { 
  def function(rdd: RDD[T]): Something  {... impl here?...}
  def typ:Type 
}

class Concrete[T:TypeTag] extends TypeAware[T] with Foo[T] with Serializable{
   def function(rdd: RDD[T]): Something  {... impl here?...}
}
```

Comment: I believe TypeApi also contains scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$PackageClassSymbol so this won't work as well

Comment: Certainly does work. (In scala 2.11) here was the merge request https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3817