# Determine the function signature of an anonymous function in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reflection, anonymous-function, scala-reflect

The context is to register a UserDefinedFunction(UDF) in spark, where the UDF is an anonymous function obtained via reflection. Since the function signature of the function is determined at runtime, I was wondering whether it is possible to do so.

Say the function impl() returns an anonymous function:

```
trait Base {}
class A extends Base{
  def impl(): Function1[Int, String] = new Function1[Int, String] {
    def apply(x: Int): String = "ab" + x.toString
  }
}
val classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(classOf[Base]).toSet[Class[_ <: Base]].toList
```

and I obtain the anonymous function in another place:

```
val clazz = classes(0)
val instance = clazz.newInstance()
val impl = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("impl").invoke(instance)
```

Now, impl holds the anonymous function but I do not know its signature, and I'd like to ask whether we can convert it into a correct function instance:

```
impl.asInstanceOf[Function1[Int, String]]   // How to determine the function signature of the anonymous function, in this case Function1[Int, String]?
```

Since scala does not support generic function, I first consider getting the runtime type of the function:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeTag}
def getTypeTag[T: TypeTag](obj: T) = typeTag[T]
val typeList = getTypeTag(impl).tpe.typeArgs
```

It will return List(Int, String), but I fail to recognize the correct function template via reflection.

Update: if the classes are defined as follows:

```
trait Base {}
class A extends Base{
  def impl(x: Int): String = {
    "ab" + x.toString
  }
}
```

where impl is the function itself and we do not know its function signature, can the impl function still be registered?

Comment: Can you clarify what you have as input? And what you'd like to be able to do.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. *"scala does not support generic function"* What does this mean? *"I fail to recognize the correct function template"* What does this mean? Why from `List(Int, String)` can't you conclude that this is a `Function1[Int, String]`?

Comment: `getTypeTag(impl())` is `TypeTag[Int => String]` aka `TypeTag[Function1[Int, String]]`.

Comment: It sounds as if OP received `Function1[_, _]` where input and output types were lost due type type erasure. However, there is no context so it's hard to tell why it was lost, or how OP can be sure that what they receive is `Function1[Int, String]` or anything else.

Comment: The context is to register a UserDefinedFunction(UDF) in spark, where the UDF is an anonymous function obtained via reflection. Since the function signature of the function is determined at runtime, I was wondering whether it is possible to do so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56991021/how-to-get-the-static-type-of-an-expression-in-scala https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62344603/scala-defining-custom-type-type-mismatch-error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72151052/the-opposite-of-compiletime-constvaluet-in-scala-3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220935/type-annotations-overriden-by-inferred-expression-type

Comment: If you use runtime reflection, all bets are off. Either you'd extract the input and output from somewhere else if possible - because the bytecode for `Function1` might not have it - or if you have a control over how this function is defined, pass some information next to the value. Hard to say without looking at any code that defines and extracts this value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75224941/scala-cast-object-based-on-reflection-symbol https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74488026/public-method-must-have-explicit-type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858588/how-do-i-view-the-type-of-a-scala-expression-in-intellij https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386964/i-want-to-get-the-type-of-a-variable-at-runtime Also type classes `shapeless.ops.function.{FnFromProduct, FnToProduct}`/`scala.util.TupledFunction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The context is to register a UserDefinedFunction(UDF) in spark, where the UDF is an anonymous function obtained via reflection. Since the function signature of the function is determined at runtime, I was wondering whether it is possible to do so.

Normally you register a UDF as follows

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder
    .master("local")
    .appName("Spark app")
    .getOrCreate()

  def impl(): Int => String = x => "ab" + x.toString

  spark.udf.register("foo", impl())

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    spark.sql("""SELECT foo(10)""").show()
    //+-------+
    //|foo(10)|
    //+-------+
    //|   ab10|
    //+-------+
  }
}
```

The signature of `register` is

```
def register[RT: TypeTag, A1: TypeTag](name: String, func: Function1[A1, RT]): UserDefinedFunction
```

aka

```
def register[RT, A1](name: String, func: Function1[A1, RT])(implicit
  ttag:  TypeTag[RT],
  ttag1: TypeTag[A1]
): UserDefinedFunction
```

What `TypeTag` normally does is persisting a type information from compile time to runtime.

So in order to call `register` you either have to know types at compile time or have to know how to construct type tags at runtime.

If you don't have access to how `impl()` is constructed at runtime and you don't have (at least at runtime) the information about types/type tags at all then unfortunately this type information is irreversibly lost because of the type erasure (`Function1[Int, String]` is just `Function1[_,_]` at runtime)

```
def impl(): Any = (x: Int) => "ab" + x.toString
```

But it's possible that you have access to how `impl()` is constructed at runtime and you know (at least at runtime) the information about types/type tags. So I assume that you don't have types `Int`, `String` statically and you can't call `typeTag[Int]`, `typeTag[String]` (as I do below) but you have somehow runtime objects of `Type`/`TypeTag`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.universe._

def impl(): Any = (x: Int) => "ab" + x.toString
val ttag1 = typeTag[Int]    // actual definition is probably different
val ttag  = typeTag[String] // actual definition is probably different
```

In such case you can call `register` resolving implicits explicitly

```
spark.udf.register("foo", impl().asInstanceOf[Function1[_,_]])(ttag.asInstanceOf[TypeTag[_]], ttag1.asInstanceOf[TypeTag[_]])
```

Well, this doesn't compile because of existential types but you can trick the compiler

```
type A
type B
spark.udf.register("foo", impl().asInstanceOf[A => B])(ttag.asInstanceOf[TypeTag[B]], ttag1.asInstanceOf[TypeTag[A]])
```

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/0b3660d646f74fb109665bad41b3ae9f

Alternatively you can use [runtime compilation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#tree-creation-via-parse-on-toolboxes) (creating a new compile time inside the runtime)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
import ScalaReflection.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox // libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value

val rm = ScalaReflection.mirror
val tb = rm.mkToolBox()
tb.eval(q"""App.spark.udf.register("foo", App.impl().asInstanceOf[$ttag1 => $ttag])""")
```

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/5b5dd4d7db0d0eebb51dd8c16735e0fb

You should provide some code how you construct `impl()` and we'll see whether it's possible to restore the types.

[Spark registered a Scala object all of the methods as a UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71438479/spark-registered-a-scala-object-all-of-the-methods-as-a-udf)

[scala cast object based on reflection symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75224941/scala-cast-object-based-on-reflection-symbol)

---

**Update.** After you get `val impl = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("impl").invoke(instance)` it's too late to restore function types (you can check that `typeList` is empty). Where function type (or type tag) should be captured is somewhere not too far from class `A`, maybe inside `A` or outside `A` but when `Int`, `String` are not lost yet. What `TypeTag` can do is persisting type information from compile time to runtime, it can't restore type information at runtime if it's lost.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
import ScalaReflection.universe._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.reflections.Reflections
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
import scala.reflect.api

object App {
  def getType[T: TypeTag](obj: T) = typeOf[T]

  trait Base
  class A extends Base {
    def impl(): Int => String = x => "ab" + x.toString 

       // NotSerializableException
    //def impl(): Function1[Int, String] = new Function1[Int, String] {
    //  def apply(x: Int): String = "ab" + x.toString
    //}

    val tpe = getType(impl())
  }

  val reflections = new Reflections()
  val classes: List[Class[_ <: Base]] = reflections.getSubTypesOf(classOf[Base]).asScala.toList

  val clazz = classes(0)
  val instance = clazz.newInstance()
  val impl = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("impl").invoke(instance)
  val functionType = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("tpe").invoke(instance).asInstanceOf[Type]
  val List(argType, returnType) = functionType.typeArgs

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("Spark app")
    .getOrCreate()

  val rm = ScalaReflection.mirror

  // (*)
  def typeToTypeTag[T](tpe: Type): TypeTag[T] =
    TypeTag(rm, new api.TypeCreator {
      def apply[U <: api.Universe with Singleton](m: api.Mirror[U]) =
        tpe.asInstanceOf[U#Type]
    })

//  type X
//  type Y
//  spark.udf.register("foo", impl.asInstanceOf[X => Y])(
//    typeToTypeTag[Y](returnType),
//    typeToTypeTag[X](argType)
//  )

  impl match {
    case impl: Function1[x, y] => spark.udf.register("foo", impl)(
      typeToTypeTag[y](returnType),
      typeToTypeTag[x](argType)
    )
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    spark.sql("""SELECT foo(10)""").show()
  }

}
```

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/2ebfae922f8a467d01b6ef18c8b8e5ad

(*) [Get a TypeTag from a Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887386/get-a-typetag-from-a-type)

<strike>Now `spark.sql("""SELECT foo(10)""").show()` throws `java.io.NotSerializableException` but I guess it's not related to reflection.</strike>

Alternatively you can use runtime compilation (instead of manual resolution of implicits and construction of type tags from types)

```
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val rm = ScalaReflection.mirror
val tb = rm.mkToolBox()
tb.eval(q"""App.spark.udf.register("foo", App.impl.asInstanceOf[$functionType])""")
```

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/ba469faeca2230890845e1532b36e2a1

One more option is to request the return type of method `impl()` as soon as we get class `A` (outside `A`)

```
class A extends Base {
  def impl(): Int => String = x => "ab" + x.toString
}

// ...
val functionType = rm.classSymbol(clazz).typeSignature.decl(TermName("impl")).asMethod.returnType
val List(argType, returnType) = functionType.typeArgs
```

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/3bd2c19d158f8241a80952c397ee5e09

---

**Update 2.** If the methods are defined as follows:

```
class A extends Base{
  def impl(x: Int): String = {
    "ab" + x.toString
  }
}
```

then runtime compilation normally should be

```
val rm = ScalaReflection.mirror
val classSymbol = rm.classSymbol(clazz)
val tb = rm.mkToolBox()

tb.eval(q"""App.spark.udf.register("foo", (new $classSymbol).$methodSymbol(_))""")
```

or

```
tb.eval(q"""App.spark.udf.register("foo", (new $classSymbol).impl(_))""")
```

but now with Spark it produces `ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.f of type scala.Function1 in instance of org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF` similarly to [Spark registered a Scala object all of the methods as a UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71438479/spark-registered-a-scala-object-all-of-the-methods-as-a-udf)

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/b0f110f4cf15e2dfd4add70f7124a7b6

But ordinary Scala runtime reflection seems to work

```
val rm = ScalaReflection.mirror
val classSymbol = rm.classSymbol(clazz)
val methodSymbol = classSymbol.typeSignature.decl(TermName("impl")).asMethod
val returnType = methodSymbol.returnType
val argType = methodSymbol.paramLists.head.head.typeSignature

val constructorSymbol = classSymbol.typeSignature.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
val instance = rm.reflectClass(classSymbol).reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol)()
val impl: Any => Any = rm.reflect(instance).reflectMethod(methodSymbol)(_)

def typeToTypeTag[T](tpe: Type): TypeTag[T] =
  TypeTag(rm, new api.TypeCreator {
    def apply[U <: api.Universe with Singleton](m: api.Mirror[U]) =
      tpe.asInstanceOf[U#Type]
  })

impl match {
  case impl: Function1[x, y] => spark.udf.register("foo", impl)(
    typeToTypeTag[y](returnType),
    typeToTypeTag[x](argType)
  )
}
```

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/763751096fe9cdb2e0d18ae4b9290a54

---

**Update 3.** One more approach is to use compile-time reflection ([macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html)) rather than [runtime reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) if you have enough information at compile time (e.g. if all the classes are known at compile time)

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object Macros {
  def registerMethod[A](): Unit = macro registerMethodImpl[A]

  def registerMethodImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)(): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val A = weakTypeOf[A]

    var children = mutable.Seq[Type]()

    val traverser = new Traverser {
      override def traverse(tree: Tree): Unit = {
        tree match {
          case _: ClassDef =>
            val tpe = tree.symbol.asClass.toType
            if (tpe <:< A && !(tpe =:= A)) children :+= tpe
          case _ =>
        }

        super.traverse(tree)
      }
    }

    c.enclosingRun.units.foreach(unit => traverser.traverse(unit.body))

    val calls = children.map(tpe =>
      q"""spark.udf.register("foo", (new $tpe).impl(_))"""
    )

    q"..$calls"
  }
}
```

```
// in a different subproject

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object App {
  trait Base

  class A extends Base {
    def impl(x: Int): String = "ab" + x.toString
  }

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("Spark app")
    .getOrCreate()

  Macros.registerMethod[Base]()

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    spark.sql("""SELECT foo(10)""").show()
  }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/6623f1f900330f8341f209e1347a0007

[Shapeless - How to derive LabelledGeneric for Coproduct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75544693/shapeless-how-to-derive-labelledgeneric-for-coproduct) (`KnownSubclasses`)

---

**Update 4.** If we replace `val clazz = classes.head` with `classes.foreach(clazz => ...` then issues with `NotSerializableException` can be fixed with inlining

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object Macros {
  def registerMethod(clazz: Class[_]): Unit = macro registerMethodImpl

  def registerMethodImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(clazz: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    val ScalaReflection = q"_root_.org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection"
    val rm = q"$ScalaReflection.mirror"
    val ru = q"$ScalaReflection.universe"
    val classSymbol = q"$rm.classSymbol($clazz)"
    val methodSymbol = q"""$classSymbol.typeSignature.decl($ru.TermName("impl")).asMethod"""
    val returnType = q"$methodSymbol.returnType"
    val argType = q"$methodSymbol.paramLists.head.head.typeSignature"

    val constructorSymbol = q"$classSymbol.typeSignature.decl($ru.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod"
    val instance = q"$rm.reflectClass($classSymbol).reflectConstructor($constructorSymbol).apply()"
    val impl1 = q"(x: Any) => $rm.reflect($instance).reflectMethod($methodSymbol).apply(x)"
    val api = q"_root_.scala.reflect.api"

    def typeToTypeTag(T: Tree, tpe: Tree): Tree =
      q"""
        $ru.TypeTag[$T]($rm, new $api.TypeCreator {
          override def apply[U <: $api.Universe with _root_.scala.Singleton](m: $api.Mirror[U]) =
            $tpe.asInstanceOf[U#Type]
        })
      """

    val impl2 = TermName(c.freshName("impl2"))
    val x = TypeName(c.freshName("x"))
    val y = TypeName(c.freshName("y"))
    q"""
      $impl1 match {
        case $impl2: _root_.scala.Function1[$x, $y] => spark.udf.register("foo", $impl2)(
          ${typeToTypeTag(tq"$y", returnType)},
          ${typeToTypeTag(tq"$x", argType)}
        )
      }
    """
  }
}
```

```
// in a different subproject

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.reflections.Reflections
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

trait Base
class A extends Base /*with Serializable*/ {
  def impl(x: Int): String = "ab" + x.toString
}

object App {
  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("Spark app")
    .getOrCreate()

  val reflections = new Reflections()
  val classes: List[Class[_ <: Base]] = reflections.getSubTypesOf(classOf[Base]).asScala.toList

  classes.foreach(clazz =>
    Macros.registerMethod(clazz)
  )

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    spark.sql("""SELECT foo(10)""").show()
  }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/c926158a9ff94a6539097c603bbedf6a

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The case is that impl() is defined in other class and I just want to use reflection to achieve the goal to "register any anonymous function as UDF", so we cannot just write "spark.udf.register("udf", new Class1.impl())" directly.

Comment: The example:
```
type A
type B
spark.udf.register("foo", impl().asInstanceOf[A => B])(ttag.asInstanceOf[TypeTag[B]], ttag1.asInstanceOf[TypeTag[A]])
```
does not compile also. The compile complains "Block cannot contain declarations".

Comment: @HangWu Please don't write code in comments. You should better update your question (press "edit").

Comment: The last runtime compilation also doesn't work. The compile complains "Can't unquote Object, consider providing an implicit instance of Liftable[Object]".

Comment: @HangWu Both of them compile https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/0b3660d646f74fb109665bad41b3ae9f https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/5b5dd4d7db0d0eebb51dd8c16735e0fb Please edit your question with details how you register UDF, how you implement `impl()` etc.

Comment: I've added more context.

Comment: Awesome! The last remaining problem is how to deal with serialization. Just adding "@transient" before impl() does not work :(

Comment: "def impl(): Function1[Int, String] = (x: Int) => "ab" + x.toString"
It works if I rewrite impl as above :)

Comment: If the classes are defined such that impl is the function directly:
class A extends Base { def impl(x: Int): String = {"ab" + x.toString} }, I was wondering whether it's possible to register impl via reflection.

Comment: If I replace the line "val clazz = classes.head" with "classes.forEach(clazz => {", the compiler throws a runtime error "Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror". I tried but cannot fix it. Is this a bug?

Comment: Even adding a pair of braces doesn't run as well https://gist.github.com/abcwuhang/4327ecb941f7fbb40514f1f0426c302e.

Comment: @HangWu Not sure. Something very Spark-specific. By the way, see one more update with macro approach.

Comment: @HangWu Regarding your gist. If I move `val rm = ScalaReflection.mirror` ouside `{...}` block then `java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror` changes to `java.io.NotSerializableException: A`. So I make `class A extends Base with Serializable`. Now the error is `java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$12` (`object not serializable (class: ...$$anon$12, value: method impl)`). Not necessarily a bug. Just Spark doesn't know how to serialize something from our reflection staff.

Comment: @HangWu I finally managed to fix `NotSerializableException` but only with inlining https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/c926158a9ff94a6539097c603bbedf6a

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/spark-serialization-errors-e0eebcf0f6e6 https://medium.com/onzo-tech/serialization-challenges-with-spark-and-scala-a2287cd51c54 https://medium.com/onzo-tech/serialization-challenges-with-spark-and-scala-part-2-now-for-something-really-challenging-bd0f391bd142 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337577/scala-reflection-with-serialization-over-spark-symbols-not-serializable

Comment: Cool. Seems that scala may integrate reflection with serialization better.

Comment: @HangWu Scala or Spark? ;)

Comment: @HangWu By the way, In Scala 3 you don't need [macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html) for inlining, [inline methods](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/inline.html) are enough.

Comment: I use scala 2.12.8.